# Access file placed in multiple directories via python

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, glob, os.walk

I have two paths and in between one directory is variable.
i want to access the xml file and make some changes with python script. 
how can i achieve  this ?

```
p1  = '/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/'
p2 = '/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml'
```

full path looks like this :

```
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/text1/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/`abc2`/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml
```

I have couple of files, placed in same manner. please help me on this. 
i tried to use blob i could not achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from glob import glob

p1  = '/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/'
p2 = '/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml'

print(glob(p1+'*'+p2))
```

Comment: @gst-frank : i am getting empty list as below,
>>> print(glob(p1+'*'+p2))
[]

Comment: @tgcloud I tested it and works. Pls, test it using simple example dirs and then try to figure out what is the problem with the actual values. With the actual values test things with shell `ls` to see if the dir exists and glob works as expected.

Comment: @gst-frank : yap, my bad that work absolutely fine.! i was missing out string quotation..! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Here `list` could be your dir contents.

```
>>> p1  = '/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/'
>>> p2 = '/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml'
>>> list = ['test','`some`']
>>> for i in list:
...     p1+i+p2
... 
'/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/test/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml'
'/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/`some`/WEB-INF/classes/j2.xml'
```